# How to stop the igraph pop up when running the code in Python?

Tags: python, igraph

I am using `igraph` to plot my `graphframes` graph and it keeps pop up the output image. I have to manually close the window so the process can continue to run.

This is my code:

```py
from igraph import Graph, plot

ig = Graph.TupleList(g.edges.collect(), directed=False)
out = plot(ig, vertex_size=10, bbox=(0, 0, 500, 500))
out.save("graph.png")
```

How can I disable the popup window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the reference for the `plot` function, you can see that there is a parameter called `target`. The default value for `target` is `None` and it tries to open an image viewer is no target is specified. You can also give it a string with a file name. https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/igraph.drawing.html#plot

Try using it like this:

```py
out = plot(ig, target='graph.png', vertex_size=10, bbox=(0, 0, 500, 500))
```

Comment: So I don't need to use `out.save()` right? It will save my plot with the `target`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The call to `out.save()` would be redundant. You should try running it without the line just to be sure.

Comment: Okay, I don't need to use `save()`. Thanks for your help.